# Leaving out '-print' from 'find' command when '-prune' is used

Tags: bash, find

I have never been able to fully understand the -prune action of the find command. But in actuality at least some of my misunderstanding stems from the effect of omitting the '-print' expression.

From the 'find' man page..

"If the expression contains no actions other than -prune, -print is performed on all files for which the expression is true."

.. which I have always (for many years) taken to mean I can leave out '-print'.

However, as the following example illustrates, there *is* a difference between using '-print' and omitting '-print', at least when a '-prune' expression appears.

First of all, I have the following 8 directories under my working directory..

```
aqua/
aqua/blue/
blue/
blue/orange/
blue/red/
cyan/blue/
green/
green/yellow/
```

There are a total of 10 files in those 8 directories..

```
aqua/blue/config.txt
aqua/config.txt
blue/config.txt
blue/orange/config.txt
blue/red/config.txt
cyan/blue/config.txt
green/config.txt
green/test.log
green/yellow/config.txt
green/yellow/test.log
```

My goal is to use 'find' to display all regular files not having 'blue' as part of the file's path. There are five files matching this requirement.

This works as expected..

```
% find . -path '*blue*' -prune -o -type f -print
./green/test.log
./green/yellow/config.txt
./green/yellow/test.log
./green/config.txt
./aqua/config.txt
```

But when I leave out '-print' it returns not only the five desired files, but also any directory whose path name contains 'blue'..

```
% find . -path '*blue*' -prune -o -type f
./green/test.log
./green/yellow/config.txt
./green/yellow/test.log
./green/config.txt
./cyan/blue
./blue
./aqua/blue
./aqua/config.txt
```

So why are the three 'blue' directories displayed?

This can be significant because often I'm trying to prune out a directory structure that contains more than 50,000 files. When that path is processed my find command, especially if I'm doing an '-exec grep' to each file, can take a huge amount of time processing files for which I have absolutely no interest. I need to have confidence that find is not going into the pruned structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit `-print` applies to the entire expression, not just the last part of it.

```
% find . \( -path '*blue*' -prune -o -type f \) -print
./green/test.log
./green/yellow/config.txt
./green/yellow/test.log
./green/config.txt
./cyan/blue
./blue
./aqua/blue
./aqua/config.txt
```

It's not decending into the pruned directories, but it is printing out the top level.

A slight modification:

```
$ find . ! \( -path '*blue*' -prune \) -type f
./green/test.log
./green/yellow/config.txt
./green/yellow/test.log
./green/config.txt
./aqua/config.txt
```

(with implicit `-a`) would lead to having the same behavior with and without `-print`.