# Please explain the implied -print action in the find command

Tags: bash, find

I recently fell into the trap of believing that if I do a `find` in `bash` that prunes certain files and then finds only the remaining files (not directories), then the output would be those remaining files.

It didn't work as I expected.

Here's a simplified example.  I've a directory structure as follows:

```
a
├── 1.log
├── 1.tgz
├── 1.txt
├── b
│   ├── 2.log
│   ├── 2.tgz
│   └── 2.txt
├── c
│   ├── 3.log
│   ├── 3.tgz
│   └── 3.txt
└── d
    └── e
        ├── 4.log
        ├── 4.tgz
        └── 4.txt
```

Let's say I want to find only the files that aren't `*.log` or `*.tgz`.  (I realise all that's left is `*.txt` files so there's an obvious way to find only those, but that's not always going to be the case, so please indulge me.)

My original command was:

```
find a \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.tgz' \) -prune -o -type f
```

I expected this to work, but it listed all files:

```
a/1.log
a/b/2.tgz
a/b/2.txt
a/b/2.log
a/d/e/4.log
a/d/e/4.txt
a/d/e/4.tgz
a/1.txt
a/1.tgz
a/c/3.tgz
a/c/3.txt
a/c/3.log
```

According the the `man` page for `find`:

> If the whole expression contains no actions other than -prune or -print,  -print  is  performed on all files for which the whole expression is true.

To my mind, the whole expression is only true for the `*.txt` files.  If I do something simple like:

```
find a -type f
```

the `-print` is implied according to the above, and all files are listed.

The thing that confused me is that if I add `-print` to the end of my original command, it works as I would expect:

```
a/b/2.txt
a/d/e/4.txt
a/1.txt
a/c/3.txt
```

Since I kind of expected that `-print` to be implied anyway, I wouldn't expect it to have any effect but clearly it does.

Could someone please explain how I should mentally parse such `find` commands so that I don't fall into traps like this again?

Comment: This could be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Comment: Thanks @Inian, that does help somewhat.  It's an unusual way of having to think!

Comment: Actually, despite searching before posting my question, I now see what's a very similarly-worded existing question!  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43263043/1999993  The asker even quotes the same bit of the `man` page as me!  The answer's not quite so helpful to me, but might help others.